# php pdo prepare in a function returns

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

Somehow my execute statement says the object has no member "execute". What is wrong?

```
class EdlSqliteDb
{
const SQLITE_DRIVER = "sqlite:";

var $dbh;
var $qIndex = Array();

//
function EdlSqliteDb($dsn) 
{
    try 
    {
        $this->dbh = new PDO(self::SQLITE_DRIVER . $dsn);
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error connecting: " . $e->getMessage() . ' ' . self::SQLITE_DRIVER . $dsn;
        die();
    }

    return;
}

//
function addQ($index,$q)
{
    $this->qIndex[$index] = $q;
}

//
function PrepareQ($index)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($this->qIndex[$index]);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Db Prepare Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
    return $stmt;
}

//
function DbExecutePrepared($index, $arrParameters)
{
    $stmt = $this->PrepareQ($index);
    if ($stmt->execute($arrParameters)) 
    {
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        return $row;
    }
    else 
    {
        print "<p>dbquery(): database table update execute error</p>\n";
        die();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is most likely due to a failed preparation.

Depending on error handling, PDO, instead of raising an exception, [may just return `false`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) .

> If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

Not entirely sure where this behaviour is defined, to be honest....

**Update:** [here it is](http://php.net/manual/en//pdo.error-handling.php). The default behaviour is to fail silently. You need to set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` for exceptions to be risen *at all times*.

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Comment: Please note: I have set `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` and also run into a situation where `PDO::prepare()` is returning `false` without raising an exception. PHP does not define when you should expect an exception or a `false`.

Comment: Coming from Python, this default error silencing in PHP shocks me. The PHP core developers may contemplate about 'Errors should never pass silently' from the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
var_dump($stmt);
```

After:

```
$stmt = $this->PrepareQ($index);
```

Probably there's something wrong with it so `$this->PrepareQ($index);` is returning null, or an object that has no `execute` method, `var_dump`ing the variable will help knowing what that variable is and debugging this issue.